# Couldn't access JS file from WEB-INF

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, maven

I have following project structure

[image: Project Structure]

In `exportPage.jsp` JSP I have included JS files as

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"/>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"/>"></script>
```

But when I run app to access the page I am getting `404` error for both URLs. URL generated is as follow:

http://localhost:8090/springmvc/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js

What I have to configure in STS to fixed this issue. Is this build path issue. By the way this is Maven type Spring Project in STS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that:**User does not have access to WEB-INF**.So,your js files are in *WEB-INF*.When page load js files download to user PC and user has no access to this folder and you get error.You must create js folder outside **WEB-INF**.You can create your views in your *WEB-INF* because user has no access directly to this folder.